# Action bar tabs showing as drop-down list

Tags: android, mobile, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I'm not able to understand this behaviour.

I have an activity with fixed tabs layout, but:
in landscape the tabs are shown as a list, whule in portrait the tabs are shown as I want.

I have read about split action bar but I don't think is the right solution.

Any idea?

**EDIT**

Here the activity with pager:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".CapsulesActivity" />
```

And here the fragment layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".CapsulesActivity$DummySectionFragment" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="290dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="20dp" >
</GridView>
```

I also post images for portrait and landscape of my app.
[image: Landscape]

[image: Portrait]

Comment: Please post your layout file.

Comment: I've posted the layout file and some screens. Ideas?

Comment: It seems to be an issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24439